# How to configure jboss eap 7.0 xa-datasources?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jboss

I'm trying to configure a jboss eap 7 server in eclipse oxygen. I have specified some xa-datasources in my standalone.xml file, but when I try to start the server I get these errors for each datasource:

1.
`Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`
2.
 `Error during crash recovery: java:jboss/jdbc/dbName (IJ031084: Unable to create connection)`

I'm pretty sure the connection strings are ok, and I don't know what else might be wrong. The format of the connection strings is fine.

Comment: How looks xml element with datasource in config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is tnsnames.ora and what does it have to do with "ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779272/what-is-tnsnames-ora-and-what-does-it-have-to-do-with-ora-12514-tnslistener-d)

Comment: Please take a look at the "Possible Duplicate" - it will probably solve your problem.  If not search SO for `TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor` and while not all results are related to java - they'll all have some things to help you out likely

Comment: I looked at it, but it didn't help, because the format of my connection strings is fine. Turns out, I had the wrong connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection URL, you had put in the xml file.Is it correct or not?